# Logitech M720 Triathlon is not connecting by bluetooth to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I have issues connecting the Logitech M720 to Ubuntu by bluetooth. It works fine over the unifying receiver but I want to connect it by bluetooth instead.

It shows in the available devices but when I click on it to pair, it just does nothing.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just solved it. I booted into Ubuntu with Bluetooth off and installed Blueman from the software center. Then I connected the mouse and it worked. I took it around 5 or 10 seconds after pairing to move but it did eventually.

Comment: this [article](https://ericasberry.com/blog/2016/09/30/pairing-a-logitech-mx-master-mouse-with-ubuntu-16-04-using-bluetooth/) helps me. essentially, run following as root: `hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1; hciconfig hci0 down; hciconfig hci0 up`